# Catching ASP.NET's Response.Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, response.redirect

I am trying to catch redirect response of asp.net from client-side by javascript/jquery but I could not manage it.

My target is catching redirect url and modifying it. Are there any way to do it?

**More Details:**
I'm converting an application to ajax style. I'm loading pages by jquery.load method so when I post a form it is loading out of the container. I know it is not a good way, but it is temprorarily best way for me.

Comment: Response.redirect happens on the server, so there's no way to handle that with JS. If your question was a little more clear we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Is there a specific result that you're trying to accomplish? Maybe someone could provide a solution for that.

Comment: ok, I gave more details over. I hope there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of catching redirect info with JavaScript. Clientside code is not even loaded when browser receives HTTP 301 or HTTP 302 headers, it automaticaly sends GET request to new URL.